# Calling an iframe by Php

Tags: php, iframe

I tried calling an Iframe like this but it did not work ! Why is it so ?

```
 <iframe id="frame" src="load.php?sinput="<?php echo $_GET["sinput"]; ?> > </iframe>
```

Comment: What part of this is your question about?

Comment: And, more to the point, bearing in mind how long it took you to ask this question, wouldn't it have been quicker to try it?

Comment: I tried it... it didnt work  :(

Comment: Every support person's worst nightmare... "it didn't work".  Can you be any more specific?

Comment: Unfortunately, people are simply REFUSING to understand the original question, which is why nobody was able to answer it. Let me do what should have been totally unnecessary, and repeat the question. Given that he has "pageX.html" that needs to called in the form of an iFrame from "pageX.php", what is the syntax for doing so? Invariably, codeGeeks will respond with variations on "why are you trying to do THAT?" instead of just answering the damn question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_GET['sinput']` needs to be within the double quotes of the `src` argument:

```
<iframe id="frame" src="load.php?sinput=<?php echo $_GET['sinput'] ?>">
</iframe>
```

Comment: What the Difference between "sinput"  and 'sinput' ?

Comment: @Adi: No difference, I just prefer not to use both when placing within a double quoted string.  Think it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put - why couldn't you :) The PHP code's output goes into the HTML markup, leading to the ?sinput= being followed just by what the $_GET['sinput'] has in PHP. However, doing that without parameter sanitization is a *very* bad idea, as a hypothetical attacker can basically input arbitrary HTML - and JavaScript! - in your page with a specifically crafted link. (See the [Wikipedia article on cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) for more information.)

Anyway, you say that it doesn't work - what does the page have there, then? Literally

```
<iframe src="load.php?sinput=<?php echo $_GET['sinput']; ?>">
```

or

```
<iframe src="load.php?sinput=">
```

? If it's the first one, then your web server is not properly recognizing the page as containing PHP code, if the second, your PHP script doesn't find anything in the $_GET['sinput'] variable.

Comment: Oh duh, see mofolo's answer - your double quotes are a bit off there. I feel stupid for not noticing.

Comment: Even i didnt notice it and started freaking out :) Stupid me